# run jar with dependecies

Tags: java, jar

I'm using log4j and slf4j in my application. I put it into jar. 
My manifest looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.runner.Main
```

My jar file located in the same folder as jars `log4j-1.2.17.jar` and etc.
But when I try to run it I've got an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.runner.control.environment.classes.utils.JxdlProperties.<init>(JxdlProperties.java:20)
    at org.runner.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

How to run it with dependencies?

Comment: Please read [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Comment: And here. [executable-jar-with-maven](http://jinahya.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/executable-jar-with-apache-maven/) if you're using maven.